# Plot3D does not show graph

Tags: plotting

Recently, I tried below code in Mathematica to plot a 3D graph.

```
Plot3D[cos[x] + tan[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

But there is no graph in the resulted figure.

On the contrary, when I tried

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

everything is fine.

Please help me figure out the problem. Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: You want `Cos[x]` and `Tan[y]`. `cos` and `tan` (note the case change) are undefined symbols. You can see this because the symbols are coloured blue. All built-in functions are in CapsCamelCase.

Comment: Thank you so much @CarlLange! I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

built in functions in Mathematica begin with capital letters.

Try `Plot3D[Cos[x] + Tan[y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]`

Thanks,

Ruth